# Embedding Animated Matplotlib in Tkinter Causes Program to Never End

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

I have searched and have been unable to figure out how to make this program end when the window closes.  It works fine for a static pyplot but when I run an animated plot, when I close the window I have to break out of the program with fn-ctrl-b.

```
#---------Imports
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import time
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
#---------End of imports

# Create figure for plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
xs = []
ys = []
zs = []

def animate(i, xs, ys, zs):
    xs.append(time.clock())
    ys.append(time.clock()+np.random.random())

    xs = xs[-100:]
    ys = ys[-100:]

    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xs, ys)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0,row=0)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(xs, ys, zs), interval=5)

tk.mainloop()
```

I appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this; for me the code runs fine. However, one thing to note is that one shouldn't mix pyplot with a custom GUI. Hence I'd recommend to remove the pyplot import and create the figure as `matplotlib.figure.Figure()`. If this solves your problem remains to be verified.

Comment: If you build everything here inside of a class that inherits from `Tk()` then when you destroy that class everything inside of it will also be destroyed.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest can you provide a link or a reason why one should not mix pyplot with Tkinter? I have not encountered this information anywhere before and I am curious as to why that would be a problem.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Can you actually reproduce OP's problem? Concerning your question: I don't have any link or explanation ready, but the problem is that the pyplot figure will be used by the pyplot figure manager as well as the specifically created `FigureCanvasTkAgg`. This *can* lead to all kinds of problems.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I cannot reporduces the OP's problem specifically but their code does not fully terminate in my IDE without forcing it to stop. The window does close but something is still hanging in the background. When I removed pyplot and used matplotlib's figure this went away. Actually after testing this issue still exist within a self contained class so I am guessing you are correct that the problem lies with pyplot here.

Comment: @Mike-SMT As I don't think that using a class or not makes any difference here, maybe you can formulate the answer such that the pyplot use is identified as the source of the problem

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I was going to edit my answer shortly. I was waiting for a reply from the OP. Trying to see if just changing the figure fixed their issue because I cannot reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer will be in OOP. I prefer using a class approach.

As ImportanceOfBeingErnest points out pyplot is likely the culprit so we should use `figure` from matplotlib here.

After using the figure import from matplotlib instead of the pyplot one I have found that any issue I noticed is now gone. This should fix your problem.

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import time
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import animation, figure


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        fig = figure.Figure()
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        self.xs = []
        self.ys = []
        self.zs = []

        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, self.animate, interval=5)

    def animate(self, event):
        self.xs.append(time.clock())
        self.ys.append(time.clock() + np.random.random())
        self.xs = self.xs[-100:]
        self.ys = self.ys[-100:]
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(self.xs, self.ys)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: This fixes my problem.  Can you explain how putting it all inside an app fixes the problem?  I am still pretty novice at Python.  Thank you so much for help!

Comment: @TheRollTideGuy my original assumption is that once the class is destroyed everything inside of it will be as well. However I am now thinking the issue you were having was related to what *ImportanceOfBeingErnest* was talking about. The pyplot figure issue. Because I am unable to fully reproduce your problem Maybe you could test my code but with the pyplot figure instead and see what happens. That would confirm if the issue really was the pyplot or the fix was the class.

Comment: In my other code (main project) I already had this code inside of a class.  The problem, in fact, turned out to be the incompatibility of pyplot and tkinter.